# Will removing a column with a Rails migration remove indexes associated with the column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

In Rails 2, will removing a column with a Rails migration also change/remove indexes associated with the column?  If not, and instead you have to also change/remove each index manually, shouldn't it instead be automated?

Thanks (from a Rails newbie)

Comment: By the way here's an interesting post that does not necessarily directly answer my question however: http://keyj.wordpress.com/2009/05/28/remove-index-with-rails-migrations/

Comment: Update: currently, it does remove the index (Rails 4.1.7).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, unfortunately you have to remove the index manually from within your migration using the [`remove_index`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table.html#method-i-remove_index) method.

Comment: for MySQL 5.1 (at least) this does not appear to be the case. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4341928/

Comment: In Rails 4 it does now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27622694/407213 (e.g.: I tried and after `remove_column ...`, `remove_index ...` throws a "Index name '...' on table '...' does not exist" <3 )

Answer (score 82):

From Rails 4 upwards, the index removes automatically with the column removal.

Comment: Although removing column will remove its index, it won't be fully reversible. Rollback will not add the index back. In this case `remove_index` is needed

Answer (score 7):

To clarify, inside a migration the syntax to remove a 2 column index is the following

```
remove_index :actions, :column => [:user_id,:action_name]
```

or by name, a worse option from my point of view

```
remove_index :actions, :name => "index_actions_on_user_id_and_action_name"
```

Comment: remove_index by name is not reversible, so it's better to use `column`

Answer (score 6):

Just as a caution, while Rails 4 *will* remove the index for you if you remove the column, you should specify the column type. Without a column type, running `rake db:rollback` will return

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

remove_column is only reversible if given a type.
```

I was experimenting with dropping foreign key columns that were indexed. Even specifying `index: true` in the change block didn't seem to make the columns reversible on rollback.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove index you should use `remove_index`, if you use `remove_column` it does remove the index but you can't run rake db:rollback. As Jim mentioned.

```
remove_column is only reversible if given a type.
```

Answer (score 0):

In Rails > 3.2.16, removing the column removes the index.