# Cannot remove an index from table in Rails 4 and PSQL 9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, rails-postgresql, database-indexes

In my schema.rb I have the following line:

```
add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
```

When I run `\di` in psql I get:

```
Schema |                             Name                             | Type  | Owner |         Table
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+-------+-------+-----------------------
 public | index_users_on_email                                         | index | alex  | users
```

Yet, if I include in a migration one of these:

- remove_index :users, name: :index_users_on_email
- remove_index :users, column: :email
- remove_index :users, :email
- execute 'DROP INDEX index_users_on_email'

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_users_on_email' on table 'users' does not exist
```

I also found this [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7909). So any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I know this is coming very late, but I just ran into something similar. Is there any chance you're renamed the 'email' column before you tried to remove the index? If so, by renaming the column, the index is getting removed. So the order would have to be:

1) remove index
2) rename column

Comment: This was my problem as well.  I was removing a column, and then tried to remove the index which included the previously removed column.

Comment: Same here. I was running a migration that removed a column then removed the index and got this error. Switched the order and it worked.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove an index by name you could write it like this:

```
remove_index(:table_name, :name => 'index_name')
```

You should look at this question as well: [What's the correct syntax for remove_index in a Rails 3.1.0 migration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028387/whats-the-correct-syntax-for-remove-index-in-a-rails-3-1-0-migration)

Comment: I had already tried removing the index by name, but got the same result. I also had read the question you mention. But thank you for the effort anyway.

Comment: You should manually check your database to see if the index actually exists.

Comment: Yes, it does exist. Running \di in psql gives: `public | index_users_on_email                                         | index | alex  | users`

Comment: @AlexPopov have you found an answer? Got the same error on MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a late answer, but I just ran into the same issue so I am writing this answer in the hopes it will help others in the future.

The [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7909) that the original asker ran into led to the solution. It appears that in Rails 3.x, [the implementation](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_name_for_remove) of `index_name_for_remove` was flawed so that it sometimes did not accept named indexes. Instead, it raised an `ArgumentError` claiming the index does not exist.

In Rails 4.x, [the implementation](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/index_name_for_remove) was changed so that passing a hash with the index name was handled correctly (I think, I do not have a Rails 4 app at the moment to test with).

If you need to handle this in Rails 3.x, looking at the source of `remove index` leads to the solution - using the `remove_index!` method.
`remove_index!` takes two arguments - the table name and the index name. So in the case of the original poster's question, this command should do the job:

`remove_index! :users, :index_users_on_email`

**Update**: After posting the answer I noticed that the original poster was asking about Rails 4, so it would seem that in certain cases there are still problems with the implementation of `index_name_for_remove` not detecting the correct index name. However, since the name of the index is known and we don't need to actually find out what the name is (which is what `index_name_for_remove` does internally), we can still use the `remove_index!` method to remove it.

Comment: For rails 3, `remove_index! :table_name, :index_name` works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### My error: Trying to remove an index on a column that I was dropping.

The migration was raising `PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  index "index_candidates_on_job_id_and_email" does not exist`:

```rb
class MergeJobAndJobCandidateModels < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  # ...
  def down
    change_table :candidates do |t|
      t.remove :job_id
      # ...
    end
    remove_index :candidates, %i[email job_id]
  end
end
```

Mistake: I was dropping the column AND trying to remove the index. Rails/Postgres will automatically remove indexes on columns that no longer exist, so there was no reason for me to be removing this index in my migration.

Hope this saves a little time to someone else out there experiencing this error.